# Texture painting margin size

Tags: texture-painting

I am painting a texture for my model using Blender "Texture Paint" mode. Is it possible to change the margin size for how much the texture gets painted over the edge of the models UV?

Regards,
Koreenium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the painting options it is called **"bleed"** and defined in pixels.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Weirdly enough I never even thought it might be the bleed.