# Strange lines appearing in model texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

Im making a model for a game and I handpainted the texture but in the render appear some strange lines in the texture (Like in the back of the character that is in the picture down below) does anyone have a idea what is causing this?

That texture part is represented on the right side of the character.

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the "[bleed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62407/texture-painting-margin-size)" parameter while painting.

Comment: Also, try zooming in closer - artifacts like this often happen from the way the projection paint works, and I zoom in and can then cover those problems